# What alternative proof can be used on this theorem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, angle

I am looking for an elegant elementary, preferrably geometric proof of the following theorem:

[image: the illustration]

It states that $a + b = x + y$.

My proof is as follows:

- $ABD = 180^\circ - x$ (adjacent angles);
- $ACD = 180^\circ - y$ (adjacent angles);
- $\angle BAC + \angle ACD + \angle BDC + \angle ABD = 360^\circ$ (sum of angles of a convex quadrilateral);
- $a+b+180^\circ - x + 180^\circ - y = 360^\circ$
- $a+b-x-y = 0$
- $a+b = x+y$, which was to be proven.

I would also like to know the name of this theorem too, if any.

Comment: Are you aware that for a triangle, "exterior angle = sum of interior angles"? If so, connect AD, and apply that.

Comment: Check out Euclid I.32

Comment: @CalvinLin This is so brilliant! Not sure why did I miss connecting AD while trying BC.